# Cannot figure out how to fix syntax error (missing operator) in query expression error in C#

Tags: c#, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I'm having an issue with an error written above and cannot find a exact way to fix it.

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select count(*) from [contractors$] where " + category + " like '*@name*'", eh.Connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "*" + name + "*";
OleDbCommand command = dataAdapter.SelectCommand;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The exact error is..

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'like '*@name*''.

I've also already looked for solutions to this problem and have attempted to adapt them to try to get this work work, but with no luck(the one above was one of the attempts)

Much thanks in advance!

Ok, so I have now change the code to this..

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select count(*) from `contractors$` where " + category + " LIKE @name", eh.Connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + name + "%";
OleDbCommand command = dataAdapter.SelectCommand;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `category`? Can you post the full SQL after it has been evaluated?

Comment: the value of category changed depending on the drop down menu, however, for the testing purposes it is 'Status'

and sure, once i get this figured out, i will post the solution

Comment: I mean do this: `Debug.WriteLine(sql);` then post what you get. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788

Comment: I beleive you have found the problem.
Select count(*) from [contractors$] where  like '@name'
Ill need to go back and see whats happenning with that text value and why it hasnt passed.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem for that. I have another error now, but ill give it a crack first before actually posting it up. Could you please write your answer in the answer thign so i could accept your answer? Thankyou so much for the help =)

Answer (score 1):

A parameter cannot be contained inside an SQL string literal. Use concatenation to build the string:

```
"... LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') ..."
```

**Update**

It seems that the value of `category` was null or empty, creating an invalid SQL statement:

```
 Select count(*) from [contractors$] where like '@name'
                                         ^^^ no category here
```

Comment: Ok, i attempted to use concat in this way
"Select count(*) from [contractors$] where " + category + " like '"+String.Concat('%',name,'%')+"'", eh.Connection

but did not work. as for removing the brackets, that created another error it seems

Comment: @Raider00321: `but did not work` Please be more precise. What was the error message? `as for removing the brackets, that created another error it seems`.  Again, please be more precise. What was the error message?  By the way, are you *sure* you are using MySQL?

Comment: the exact error was
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'like '@name''.
like before